# Unsupported WinAPI error code with GetConsoleCharType

Tags: c, winapi

I have decided to explore WinAPI undocumented function, because some of them can still be used and can do things that are not possible without them (for example: `GetConsoleCommandHistory` or `MessageBoxTimeout`).

When I tried to import `GetConsoleCharType` from kernel32.dll with a declaration that I found on the internet. When I ran it I got the error code `16385` from `GetLastError`. I tried to run it in `FormatMessage` to retrieve the error message but then `FormatMessage` failed with code `15100` from `GetLastError`. I entered [windows error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) page and I saw that they only support error codes between 0 and 15999. Does anyone can help me understand this error?

function declaration is from https://doxygen.reactos.org/df/d28/dll_2win32_2kernel32_2client_2console_2console_8c.html

My code:

```
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibraryA("kernel32.dll");
if (hModule)
{
    puts("Kernel32 loaded!");
    BOOL(WINAPI * GetConsoleCharType)(HANDLE hConsole, COORD Coord, PDWORD Type);
    GetConsoleCharType = (decltype(GetConsoleCharType))GetProcAddress(hModule, "GetConsoleCharType");
    if(GetConsoleCharType)
    {
        puts("Function loaded!");
        DWORD type = 0;
        if (GetConsoleCharType(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), { 0, 0 }, &type))
            puts("Function worked!");
        else
        {
            printf("Function failed with code %lu\n", GetLastError());
            char* msg;
            if(FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                NULL, GetLastError(),
                MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                (LPSTR)&msg, 0, NULL))
            {
                printf("Error: %s", msg);
                LocalFree(msg);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("FormatMessage failed with code %lu\n", GetLastError());
            }
        }
        FreeLibrary(hModule);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Kernel32 loaded!
Function loaded!
Function failed with code 16385
FormatMessage failed with code 15100
```

Comment: What makes you think that `GetConsoleCharType()` uses `GetLastError()` to report errors? It is undocumented, you don't know if it even reports errors at all. Case in point, the [source code](https://doxygen.reactos.org/df/d28/dll_2win32_2kernel32_2client_2console_2console_8c.html) you linked to doesn't call `SetLastError()`, so the return value of `GetLastError()` would be meaningless.

Comment: For getting [the character attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/char-info-str), [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo) can achieve this purpose.

Comment: [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror): *"The Return Value section of the documentation for each function that sets the last-error code notes the conditions under which the function sets the last-error code."* Without documentation you do not know those conditions. Consequently it is *never* safe to call `GetLastError` after calling a function without documentation.

Comment: I have tried to use `SetLastError` before this code to check if it changes. It does.

Comment: The fact that the calling thread's last error code changes is no indication that its value is part of the contract. Neither is no change any indication for anything. A contract is not something you can derive from observations. A contract is a written document. Naturally, undocumented library functions do not come with a contract. Put another way: The contract for undocumented API calls is: Don't use.

Answer (score 1):

`GetConsoleCharType` return `C0074001` - you can get it via `RtlGetLastNtStatus()`. really call handled inside *conhost.exe*. if you attach debugger to it you can view next debug print:

```
onecore\windows\core\console\open\src\server\apidispatchersinternal.cpp(23)\ConhostV2.dll!00007FFFB6D35863: (caller: 00007FFFB6D35681) ReturnHr(5) tid(ae4) 80004001 Not implemented
    Msg:[Deprecated API attempted: 0x00000007]
```

call handled inside

```
HRESULT ApiDispatchers::ServerDeprecatedApi(_CONSOLE_API_MSG * const,int * const)
{
  return wil::details::in1diag3::Return_HrMsg(*,E_NOTIMPL, 
  "onecore\windows\core\console\open\src\server\apidispatchersinternal.cpp");
}
```

it return `E_NOTIMPL (0x80004001)` then it transformed

```
80004001 -> 4001 -> 4001 | c0070000 = c0074001
```

finally `RtlNtStatusToDosError` converted it to `0x4001 = 16385`